# Is there a way to dynamically loop the docxtemplater in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, docx, docxtemplater

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to create a loop in my react native using **[Docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/)**, but I would like to control the number of times this loop will repeat itself in the document depending on the number of items in my array, as if it were **for** or **foreach**.

This is part of the code I'm using:

```
//Array with the data that will be accessed,can reach a maximum of 12 items
export const collections = [
{name: 'item 1', unitMeasure: 'TRIP/UNIT', value: '100'}
{name: 'item 2', unitMeasure: 'TRAVEL', value: '200'}
{name: 'item 3', unitMeasure: 'UNIT', value: '300'}
{name: 'item 4', unitMeasure: 'TRIP/UNIT', value: '400'}]

}

//Code that will be used to create the loop in the document
doc.render({

"collect": [
         { name: collections[0].name, unit: collections[0].unitMeasure, value: collections[0].value},
         { name: collections[1].name, unit: collections[1].unitMeasure, value: collections[1].value},
         { name: collections[2].name, unit: collections[2].unitMeasure, value: collections[2].value},
         { name: collections[3].name, unit: collections[3].unitMeasure, value: collections[3].value},
          ])}
```

My question is whether I can shorten this part of the loop and do something similar to what I do in C#, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collections.Length; i++)
        {
            name: collections[i].name, unit: collections[i].unitMeasure, value: collections[i].value
        }
```

I tried using **for** and **foreach** but I didn't have success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can achieve the same iteration functionality as a `for` loop with array methods such as `map()`. When using Docxtemplater, you generally don't need to manually construct your data objects for each iteration; instead, you can directly pass the entire array as the context for the template rendering process. Here is how you do it:

```
export const collections = [
  { name: 'item 1', unitMeasure: 'TRIP/UNIT', value: '100' },
  { name: 'item 2', unitMeasure: 'TRAVEL', value: '200' },
  { name: 'item 3', unitMeasure: 'UNIT', value: '300' },
  { name: 'item 4', unitMeasure: 'TRIP/UNIT', value: '400' }
];

// The actual code to render the document would look something like this:
doc.render({
  collect: collections.map(item => ({
    name: item.name,
    unit: item.unitMeasure,
    value: item.value
  }))
});
```

In the above example, we use the `map()` method to transform `collections` into the format expected by Docxtemplater. This procedure automatically handles any number of items within your `collections` array.

Please ensure that your Docxtemplater template has the appropriate looping syntax. With Docxtemplater, you usually define loops in the template with the `{#tagName}` and `{/tagName}` syntax.

For example, your Word template would have something like:

```
{#collect}
Name: {name}
Unit Measure: {unit}
Value: {value}
{/collect}
```

When Docxtemplater processes this template with the context provided by your `collect` array, it will repeat the content within the `{#collect}` and `{/collect}` tags for each object in the array.